# Can I find $\frac{dm}{dt}$ where $m$ is the relativistic mass of a particle?

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, mass, time

So, recently I learned the basics of Special Relativity, and I found out that the mass of a body increases with the increase in its velocity as given by the Relativistic Mass equation:
$m=\frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ 
So I wanted to find $\frac{dm}{dt}$ for such cases.
Here's my method: 
$F=\frac{dp}{dt}$
Also,
$F=m\frac{dv}{dt}\gamma$ 
where $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ 
$p=mv\gamma$ 
Substituting value of $p$ in $F$, we get:
$F=\frac{d(mv\gamma)}{dt}$
Breaking the differentiation and equating it with $F=m\frac{dv}{dt}\gamma$, we get: 
$\frac{dm}{dt}\gamma=-\frac{d\gamma}{dt}m$
After finding $\frac{d\gamma}{dt}$, and substituting,we get: 
$\frac{dm}{dt}=\frac{mv\gamma}{c^2}=\frac{p}{c^2}$ 
Is it correct?

Comment: Hi @Deep and welcome to PSE. Why not simply differentiate the first expression wrt t?

Comment: The quantity you're computing already has two perfectly good names. They are energy over c^2 and momentum over v. The third name of "relativistic mass" is not well justified and discouraged on this site: https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/mass-energy-matter-etc/more-on-mass/the-two-definitions-of-mass-and-why-i-use-only-one/

Comment: Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133376/123208

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that $F = m \frac{dv}{dt}\gamma$ is not correct. You should instead have $$F = \frac{d}{dt} (\gamma m_0v) = v\frac{dm}{dt} + m\frac{d}{dt}(v)$$ where note $m = \gamma m_0$.

However, to find $\frac{dm}{dt}$ I would rather differentiate the expression $$ m=\frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} $$
giving $$ \frac{dm}{dt} = m_0\frac{d}{dt} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} $$
Let me know if you need me to perform the last differentiation.

Comment: So,  the original $\frac{dm}{dt}$ will be $m_0\frac{v}{c^2}\gamma^3$. Thanks for clearing it out.